# Creating Generic Strongly Typed DataTable Explorer

Tags: generics

I'm trying to create a generic class that will offer some additional features to any strongly typed data table.  Many of these features use a function that allow the user to specify criteria to find rows within the strongly type data table using the strongly typed fields of the type.  The problem happens when I try to pass in a Func(Of T, Boolean) into a Where clause that expects Func(Of datarow, Boolean).  My generic class ensures that T inherits from datarow so I don't understand why I'm getting an invalid cast exception.

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim strongTable As New StrongTypedTable
        Dim explorer As New DependencyExplorer(Of StrongTypedRow)(strongTable)
        Dim row As StrongTypedRow = explorer.FindRows(Function(r) r.MyColumn = 1)
    End Sub
End Module

Public Class StrongTypedTable
    Inherits DataTable
    Public Sub New()
        Columns.Add(New DataColumn("MyColumn", GetType(Integer)))
    End Sub
    Protected Overrides Function GetRowType() As Type
        Return GetType(StrongTypedRow)
    End Function
    Protected Overrides Function NewRowFromBuilder(builder As DataRowBuilder) As DataRow
        Return New StrongTypedRow(builder)
    End Function
End Class

Public Class StrongTypedRow
    Inherits DataRow
    Friend Sub New(builder As DataRowBuilder)
        MyBase.New(builder)
    End Sub
    Public Property MyColumn() As String = MyBase.Item("MyColumn")
End Class

Public Class DependencyExplorer(Of rowType As DataRow)
    Private _table As DataTable
    Public Function FindRows(ByVal whereClause As Func(Of rowType, Boolean)) As IEnumerable(Of rowType)
        Return _table.AsEnumerable.Where(whereClause)
    End Function
    Public Sub New(ByVal table As DataTable)
        _table = table
    End Sub
End Class
```